# What permissions should a logrotate file have?

Tags: logrotate

TL;DR: **Difference between `su pi mail` and `create 666 pi mail` in `/etc/logrotate.conf`.**

I am using a script to monitor a service. I have added said script in `crontab`. `crontab` runs the script every **one minute**.

I have found this script online and it works pretty good, but it writes the logs to `/var/mail/pi` and that file does not rotate.

These are the permissions for `/var/mail` and `/var/mail/pi` :

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail       4096 Oct 15 13:48 mail
-rw-rw---- 1 pi   mail 1425632 Oct 15 13:49 pi
```

In `/etc/logrotate.conf` I have added:

```
/var/mail/pi {
    rotate 7
    daily
    su pi mail
}
```

Running `logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf` returns, among other rotating patterns, the following:

```
rotating pattern: /var/mail/pi  after 1 days (7 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
switching euid to 1000 and egid to 8
error: error switching euid to 1000 and egid to 8: Operation not permitted
error: error creating output file /var/lib/logrotate/status.tmp: Permission denied
```

Running `sudo logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf` returns:

```
rotating pattern: /var/mail/pi  after 1 days (7 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
switching euid to 1000 and egid to 8
considering log /var/mail/pi
  Now: 2019-10-15 14:46
  Last rotated at 2019-10-15 14:35
  log does not need rotating (log has been already rotated)
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
```

This works ! I have been booting up the raspberry for the past couple of days and until now it has created log files accordingly: `pi` and `pi.1` that contain logs from their respective day.

But, from what I found on the forums, using `su pi mail` is not recommended. As such, I have tried replacing `su pi mail` with `create 666 pi mail`.

With `create` I have the following situation:

`sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf` returns: `skipping "/var/mail/pi" because parent directory has insecure permissions`

`logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf` returns: `error: error renaming /var/mail/pi.1 to /var/mail/pi.2: Permission denied`

If I couldn't force the rotation using `sudo` I assumed that using `create` won't work.

## EDIT1:

I've just booted up the Rapberry and `create` made a new log file, but deleted the yesterday log file.